# HAProxy rspadd or set-header

Tags: haproxy, http-headers

I am currently trying to improve my HAProxy HTTPS configuration.
There seems to be two ways to set additional fields to response headers in HAProxy.
I currently use `http-response set-header`, which should, if I understand it right:

1. Check if the field exist
2. If it exists, delete it
3. Set the field to the new value

Some people use `rspadd` instead, which should simply append the field at the end of the response header.

When working with sensitive fields like for HSTS, `set-header` feels safer  on the paper.
Is there any real difference between both ?
If yes which one should I prefer when setting sensitive fields in my headers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `http-response` commands are newer (added in 1.5), adding additional functionality and flexibility to the older `rspadd`/`rspdel`/etc commands.  While they'll both work, it's probably better to stick with http-response for future-compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

You use them depending on what you need: add to add a new value, set to replace it. If there is sensitive data that can be injected into the headers, of course you are going to use `set-header`.